# How can I call an AJAX funtion from server side in Express/Node JS?

Tags: node.js, express

Following is my `POST` function in Node js. I want to call a funtion in my client side HTML to display an error message on the page.

```
router.post('/',(req,res)=>{

    const data = JSON.stringify({
        institute_name: req.body.institute_name,
        email : req.body.email,
        password : req.body.password
    })
    const options = { 
        host:'localhost',
        port:'8888',
        path:'/registerInstitute',
        method:'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        }
    }
    const req1 =  http.request(options, (res1)=>
    {

        const status = res1.statusCode

        if (status == 201)
        {
            //admin created
            res.redirect('/?account_created=true')
        }

        else if ( status == 409)
        {
            //CALL AJAX FUNCTION TO DISPLAY ERROR MSG
        }

    })

    req1.write(data)
    req1.end()
})
```

Comment: You cannot call a client side function in server-side code. Return a response (e.g. an error code) to the client and change the client code so that it does an Ajax request depending on that response.

Comment: Also, don't use the `http` module. There are several mistakes in your code already (like not specifying a `Content-Length` header). Use the [`request` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request), it does these things correctly and is much easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is NO. But there are workarounds to do so and I've demonstrated the one that will suite your scenario

**Sockets**

You can use web sockets to trigger event to notify client to run specific function

On service side you can do something like this:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80); // initiate socket.io server
if (
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  if ( error == 403 ) {
    socket.emit('runErrorFunction', { error: "error data" });
  }
});
```

You can do something like this on client side:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost'); // connect to server
  socket.on('runErrorFunction', function (data) { // listen to runErrorFunction event raised by the server
   // Here goes your error showing logic
   
  });
</script>
```

Here is the link for more info [Socket.io](http://socket.io/)

Comment: Since the client is the one who *initiated* the HTTP request, it's a complete waste to send the result though a socket. Send the result though the HTTP response, exactly as it's supposed to be.